# How to install playwright on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, tiktok

Halo good people,

I want to scrape data from TikTok by using TikTokApi by David Teather. I stuck on installing step.
Here are installing guide from github

```
pip install TikTokApi
python -m playwright install
```

I stuck on second line installation

```
File "<ipython-input-9-33e88bce12a3>", line 1
  python -m playwright install
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess the trouble are on environment, but how can I find on Jupyter Notebook ?
I also attached tutorial on **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwLmLfVI-VQ)** by David Teather itself using Visual Studio Code

thank you for any help!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run `python -m playwright install` as python code rather than a shell command. Try running `!python -m playwright install` to signal to jupyter that this a shell command rather than python code. I'm curious how you managed to run `pip install TikTokApi`? That is also a shell command and should only work if you use the ! prefix too.

Comment: Cool, its pretty worked, thank you! For the first line there was no issue, I just run `pip install TikTokApi` @Andrew-Harelson.

Comment: Neat, I wouldn't have expected the `pip install` to just work like that. I've submitted that fix as an answer to the question, can you accept it to better help someone who runs into this in the future? @Nanda Rukmana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run `python -m playwright install` as python code rather than a shell command. Try running `!python -m playwright install` to signal to jupyter that this a shell command rather than python code. Use the ! prefix anytime you need to run a shell command on your environment in jupyter.